# Remove italics style in bibliography, use only upright font shape

Tags: bibtex, italic

I have a question on the font style of the bibliography.

My references use italics for book titles. Is there any command I can set to make sure all text in the bibliography is in one style only, i.e., the upright style?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It is considered a lot better to put in some code that will compile, as it makes it a lot easier for us to copy it into our text editor and work with it, and see exactly what it is you are trying to do. The answer might very well depend upon how you create yout bibliography.

Comment: Which bibliography style file do you use? It's the file specified in the argument of the `\bibliographystyle` command.

Answer (score 10):

What should work for any bibliography style using either `\em` (e.g., `plain`) or `\emph` (e.g., `plainnat`) or the more basic `\itshape` is to put the bibliography inside a group and to issue `\let\itshape\upshape` at the start of this group.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\begingroup
\let\itshape\upshape

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello guys, I am using lyx so default style is ieeetr, so I choose plain style, but nothing changed. I am using a customized format package, could that be the problem overwriting my bibtex style?

Comment: @pengcheng Possible. But try to add \begingroup\let\itshape\upshape and \endgroup as "Evil Red Text" (LaTeX Code) at the appropriate places in your document body.

Comment: Worked for me too with IEEEtran style, thank's a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Based on the following answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/296150

For biblatex, you can disable all emphasizing (italics) with the following:

```
\makeatletter
\renewrobustcmd*{\mkbibemph}{}
\protected\long\def\blx@imc@mkbibemph#1{#1}
\makeatother
```