# How to change part of reference font style

Tags: biblatex, fonts

I want to change the bib style(use biblatex) for the defualt setting, the original bibstyle looks like

[image]

I want to change the "*Mathematical methods of classical mechanics*" fontstyle to "Mathematical methods of classical mechanics"

How can I achieve this?A related question [change citation font style using natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/384188/189902) which does provide with a solution for my question I want to change the font for book name to times new Roman

Added:Similarily the Jornal name in the defualt setting it's *Itatly* style, can I change it to Times New Roman?

Comment: I found a slippery way to do this ,just remove \emph{...} in the bbl file and recomplie it realize the effiect

Comment: Either of the two solutions in the suggested duplicate should work I think. If both of them don't work then you should provide the code of your document in such a way that we can reproduce the reference that you have now.

Comment: So did it work? If not then we can leave the question open and try to find another solution.

Comment: Yeah it works thank you @Marijn  , by the way I have another question ,how to remove the  "   from "title of the paper"

Comment: I mean "title of the paper"    to  title of the paper.

Comment: in your screenshot above I don't see any ", so I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/462133/35864

Comment: Thank you , I used the natbib package ,and when I \DeclareFieldFormat{title}{#1}  it says :Package biblatex Error: Incompatible package 'natbib'. \blx@packageincompatibility  ? @moewe

Comment: In the original question it says you use `biblatex` (which is incompatible with `natbib`). There `\DeclareFieldFormat` would do the job. But if you use `natbib` or indeed any `\bibliography`-style based solution, then you probably either need a trick like https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/80130/35864 or need to modify the style (though what exactly needs to be/can be done depends on the style you are using).